# PHP append custom header to redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-headers

I want to do no redirect of a request if a custom header is set (just proceed the request as it is). The htaccess part of that look like the following:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP:My-Header} !=1
RewriteRule ^somefolder/(.*)$ /someAuthentication.php&url=$1 [QSA,R=302,L]
```

The authentication where the header is set:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect'); // ...to prevent browser caching of redirects
header('My-Header: 1');
header('Location: /somefolder/' . $_GET['url']); // ... redirect to previously requested file
```

But if I e.g. redirect to some other script there and check the existing headers with `getallheaders()`, it seems like `My-Header` was not send as request header what explains why i am just getting `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

Do i misunderstand the usage / definition of headers, set the header incorrectly or is the htaccess condition faulty?
Because in my opinion it should be correct as it is, like:

```
request file 
    -> if header set 
        -> ignore redirect (pass through)
    -> if header is not set 
        -> redirect
            -> set header
                -> redirect to request file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's `header` function sets a **response header**. It's the headers going from the server to the client. The client will initiate a redirect based on the `307` response header. That redirect takes the form of a completely new HTTP **request** formed by the client. That request will not contain any of the previous *response headers*.

In a nutshell: there's no way you can make the client send any one specific *header* during a redirect. Put some sort of flag into the URL itself instead, that's the only thing guaranteed to be consistent between the redirect response and request.

Comment: Indeed, that sounds more logical to me. The client is doing the request afterwards, not the server. Thanks a lot!